# CSS HTML dropdown menu not showing full text and text not aligned

Tags: html, css

I have edited this post as it has partially solved my problem. However, i am faced with a new problem now and i do not wish to create a new question in case its deemed of spamming. currently, my add subject, drop subject, delete subject, manual crawl is not centralised even though i have specified it to be text-align center in #menu li li a. The sub menu's executive summary is also cut off. May I know how can i expand the submenu and centralise all my text?
Thank you!
Here is my code (i am really sorry because i do not have a jsfiddle acct and is on the waiting list):

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Executive Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" > Visual Analytics</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" >Settings</a>
        <ul>                                        
            <li><a href="#">Add Subject</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete Subject</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Edit Subject</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#" >Manual Crawl</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Executive Summary</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

​

**CSS**

```
     #menu {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 35px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 35px; 
}

#menu a {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; 
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px; 
    margin: 0 3px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul ul {
   display: none;
   width: 10em; /* Width to help Opera out */
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 35px;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   z-index: 1; 
}

#menu li li a{
    height: 35px; 
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px; 
    margin: 0 3px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li li a:hover{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

​

Comment: I'd like to be able to paste this into something like jsfiddle.net, but because you've included your server-side code, instead of your HTML output, this is impossible. Consider posting the resulting HTML.

Comment: Thank you Diodeus. i have edited my post as requested. but its not showing on jsfiddle. please help me if you can. thank you so much!

Comment: can anyone help me with my new problem please? thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This should get you running:

```
#menu ul, #menu li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
}

#menu ul li {
   float:left;
   position:relative;
}
#menu ul li a {
   display:block;
   height:35px;
   margin-right:5px;
}
#menu ul li ul {
   display: none;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top:40px;
   left:0   
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   z-index:1;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
   display:block;
   height:35px;
   width:130px
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#menu ul li ul li a:hover{
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

One thing you missed is to set `position:relative` for the PARENT of the sub-menu. This is important because this resets the origin for the child item. I've also cleaned things up and removed some redundant declarations. You may need to re-style your text a bit.

One important point: All styling of the menu (other than positioning) should be applied to the A-tag, not the LI. This includes fonts. bg colours etc.

See: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Answer (score 1):

Use a combinaison of `position: relative` and `position: absolute;` to fix your problem
See the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VDmJj/1/

Comment: thank you. but i realise when i hover over the submenu, the highlighted block is not in full. any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Add :

1) position:relative; to #menu ul li 
2) top:30px; left:10px; to #menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.hover ul 
3) width:180px; to #menu ul li ul (this can depend on the sub menu items)

This would give you the desired result by doing minimal changes. Though the css is a bit complicated for the task it is performing i.e. it can be done pretty simple by following method:

http://jsfiddle.net/tPBmV/

Here is another fiddle i found based on jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YfjzP/

Its not made by me but you could find it useful if you are comfortable enough to implement jquery.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check out the fiddle. Did a lot of CSS changes: http://jsfiddle.net/wAGGA/

#### CSS:

```
 #menu {
   width:1200px;
height:35px;
padding:0px;
clear:both;
background-color:#000;
 }
 #menu ul{
list-style:none;padding:0 0 0 400px;margin: auto;display:block;
}

#menu ul li {
   list-style:none;display:inline;float:left;width:auto;height:35px;padding:0px;line-height:35px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; }
#menu ul li a{
   display:block;height:35px; width: auto;float:left;text-decoration:none;padding:0 0 0 25px; margin:0px 3px 0px 3px;color:#fff;text-align:center;}
#menu ul li ul {
   display: none;
   width: 200px; /* Width to help Opera out */
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
#menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   z-index:1;
   top: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    right: 0;
}
#menu ul li ul li {display: block; float: none; width: 100%}   
#menu ul li ul li a{
   display:block;
    height:35px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 0 0 25px; 
    margin:0px 3px 0px 3px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}
   #menu ul li ul li a:hover{
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   }​
```

Comment: the submenu is wrong positioned and cannot be used. you must change that.

Comment: the css is very messy. so didn't see fully.

Answer (score 0):

add margin-top to sub menu like this

```
#menu ul li:hover ul, #menu ul li.hover ul{
margin-top:40px
}
```